# gulp not compiling scss

Tags: sass, gulp

why he does not see the bootstrap class?
If I remove all the @extend works normally

```
Error: ".navbar" failed to @extend "navbar-light".
   The selector "navbar-light" was not found.
   Use "@extend navbar-light !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.
    on line 11 of app/styles/app.scss
>>   @extend navbar-light;
   --^
```

> > app.scss

does not see @extend bootstrap class, but why?   (If I remove all the @extend, bootstrap styles compiling normally)

```
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import 'fotorama/fotorama';


.navbar {
  color: red;
  @extend navbar-light;
  @extend bg-faded;
}
```

My gulp task

```
var sassPaths = [
'node_modules'
];

gulp.task('styles', () => (
gulp.src(['app/styles/app.scss'])
    .pipe(sass({
        includePaths: sassPaths,
        errLogToConsole: true,
        indentedSyntax: false
    }))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min', basename: 'app'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/styles'))
));
```

Comment: If it's a class you need to put a period in front of the name, like any other class.

Comment: LOL, im stupid. Ty and sry :)